# TeXLive-2015: Updating packages on OS X Mavericks does not work with 'TeX Live Utility.app'

Tags: texlive, mactex, updating, mac

I recently installed the *Full TeX Live 2015 Distribution* (having used the 2014 distribution before).

Now when I want to update packages with the help of the *TeX Live Utility.app*, the following happens:

1. I see three *"texlive.infra*"* packages offered:

   [image: Initial TeX Live Utility screen]
2. I select the packages, go to menu *"Action -> Reinstall Selected Packages"* and click:

   [image: TeX Live Utility screen after selections]
   [image: TeX Live Utility re-install confirmation dialog]
3. The action is not performed. Instead a message pops up, saying that I didn't have the required 2015 installation:

   [image: TeX Live Utility message]
4. Checking the TeX Live activation in Mac OS X's *System Preferences* however shows this status:

   [image: Mac OS X System Preferences status for activated TeX Live]

**What can I do to rectify this situation?**

I did run `sudo ./texdistmgr activate TeXLive-2015` but this didn't change a thing. I also activated TeXLive-2014 and back 2015, to no avail....

---

### Update

As asked by the first comment, I did the following: wo

```
kp@mbp:Programs>  sudo tlmgr  update --all --self
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2015/tlpkg/backups
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] update: texlive.infra [302k] (37488 -> 37738) ... done
Restarting tlmgr to complete update ...
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.sciserv.eu/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2015/tlpkg/backups
[  1/119] auto-remove: fixocgx ... done
[  2/119, ??:??/??:??] update: Asana-Math [482k] (35339 -> 37556) ... done
[  3/119, 00:04/17:18] update: animate [3108k] (36484 -> 37617) ... done
[  4/119, 00:11/06:23] update: babel-french [310k] (36759 -> 37701) ... done
[  5/119, 00:14/07:29] update: babel-spanglish [6k] (36995 -> 37629) ... done
[  6/119, 00:16/08:32] update: beebe [356k] (34738 -> 37656) ... done
[  7/119, 00:18/08:48] update: biblatex-caspervector [354k] (37102 -> 37600) ... done
[  8/119, 00:21/09:29] update: biblatex-fiwi [560k] (32629 -> 37721) ... done
[  9/119, 00:26/10:28] update: biblatex-philosophy [793k] (36690 -> 37527) ... done
[ 10/119, 00:34/11:53] update: bidi [3611k] (37133 -> 37745) ... done
[ 11/119, 00:47/10:14] update: bohr [419k] (35530 -> 37657) ... done
[ 12/119, 00:50/10:25] update: c90 [96k] (15878 -> 37676) ... done
[ 13/119, 00:51/10:32] update: chemformula [954k] (36722 -> 37722) ... done
[ 14/119, 00:55/10:23] update: chemgreek [708k] (36869 -> 37729) ... done
[ 15/119, 00:57/10:06] update: cjkutils [35k] (37078 -> 37693) ... done
[ 16/119, 00:58/10:15] update: cntperchap [269k] (37338 -> 37572) ... done
[ 17/119, 01:00/10:22] update: colorspace [112k] (37329 -> 37573) ... done
[ 18/119, 01:02/10:37] update: csplain [94k] (37280 -> 37616) ... done
[ 19/119, 01:03/10:43] update: ctanify [38k] (35888 -> 37571) ... done
[ 20/119, 01:05/11:01] update: ctex [991k] (37467 -> 37720) ... done
[ 21/119, 01:08/10:40] update: curve2e [666k] (28507 -> 37708) ... done
[ 22/119, 01:10/10:27] update: cyber [257k] (36633 -> 37658) ... done
[ 23/119, 01:12/10:33] update: cybercic [197k] (36634 -> 37659) ... done
[ 24/119, 01:14/10:42] update: dccpaper [445k] (36109 -> 37647) ... done
[ 25/119, 01:18/10:57] update: diadia [449k] (37330 -> 37656) ... done
[ 26/119, 01:21/11:02] update: doclicense [337k] (36729 -> 37640) ... done
[ 27/119, 01:24/11:12] update: dozenal [416k] (36169 -> 37698) ... done
[ 28/119, 01:27/11:18] update: eledmac [1977k] (37131 -> 37699) ... done
[ 29/119, 01:33/10:45] update: elocalloc [154k] (37339 -> 37644) ... done
[ 30/119, 01:35/10:53] update: enotez [465k] (32873 -> 37678) ... done
[ 31/119, 01:39/11:04] update: fbb [2997k] (36939 -> 37585) ... done
[ 32/119, 01:49/10:30] update: fge [176k] (24732 -> 37628) ... done
[ 33/119, 01:59/11:22] update: fira [11977k] (37336 -> 37565) ... done
[ 34/119, 02:41/09:56] update: forest [958k] (37186 -> 37575) ... done
[ 35/119, 02:46/09:57] update: garuda-c90 [5k] (30642 -> 37677) ... done
[ 36/119, 02:48/10:04] update: genealogytree [3027k] (36048 -> 37648) ... done
[ 37/119, 02:58/09:49] update: isodoc [2027k] (34734 -> 37549) ... done
[ 38/119, 03:06/09:44] update: iwhdp [397k] (35382 -> 37552) ... done
[ 39/119, 03:09/09:48] update: jumplines [253k] (35965 -> 37553) ... done
[ 40/119, 03:20/10:18] update: koma-script [11248k] (37384 -> 37734) ... done
[ 41/119, 04:01/09:43] update: l3build [567k] (37132 -> 37679) ... done
[ 42/119, 04:06/09:48] update: l3experimental [3761k] (35669 -> 37621) ... done
[ 43/119, 04:21/09:42] update: l3kernel [6810k] (36423 -> 37621) ... done
[ 44/119, 04:44/09:25] update: l3packages [1591k] (35669 -> 37621) ... done
[ 45/119, 04:59/09:40] update: latex [12665k] (37361 -> 37737) ... done
[ 46/119, 05:45/09:19] update: latexpand [7k] (36125 -> 37592) ... done
[ 47/119, 05:46/09:21] update: leadsheets [832k] (36029 -> 37735) ... done
[ 48/119, 05:50/09:21] update: listings [1534k] (35124 -> 37534) ... done
[ 49/119, 05:55/09:18] update: maths-symbols [197k] (37500 -> 37547) ... done
[ 50/119, 05:58/09:22] update: mathtools [1032k] (37331 -> 37587) ... done
[ 51/119, 06:04/09:24] update: media9 [6536k] (37332 -> 37662) ... done
[ 52/119, 06:25/09:12] update: musixtex [1957k] (37025 -> 37576) ... done
[ 53/119, 06:31/09:08] update: nfssext-cfr [160k] (19322 -> 37601) ... done
[ 54/119, 06:32/09:08] update: norasi-c90 [10k] (30642 -> 37675) ... done
[ 55/119, 06:33/09:10] update: pagecolor [409k] (25500 -> 37646) ... done
[ 56/119, 06:35/09:10] update: pdfpages [346k] (37333 -> 37567) ... done
[ 57/119, 06:37/09:11] update: pkuthss [515k] (37123 -> 37719) ... done
[ 58/119, 06:42/09:14] update: plain [169k] (37363 -> 37747) ... done
[ 59/119, 06:43/09:15] update: poemscol [719k] (31338 -> 37724) ... done
[ 60/119, 06:47/09:16] update: pst-barcode [377k] (37353 -> 37586) ... done
[ 61/119, 06:52/09:20] update: pst-solides3d [5934k] (35122 -> 37718) ... done
[ 62/119, 07:08/09:07] update: pstricks [6797k] (35439 -> 37707) ... done
[ 63/119, 07:26/08:53] update: ptex2pdf [12k] (37120 -> 37566) ... done
[ 64/119, 07:28/08:55] update: reflectgraphics [256k] (35064 -> 37748) ... done
[ 65/119, 07:29/08:55] update: regexpatch [541k] (29543 -> 37631) ... done
[ 66/119, 07:31/08:55] update: resumecls [151k] (29417 -> 37570) ... done
[ 67/119, 07:33/08:56] update: sectionbox [190k] (15878 -> 37749) ... done
[ 68/119, 07:35/08:58] update: siunitx [729k] (36118 -> 37680) ... done
[ 69/119, 07:38/08:58] update: suftesi [1015k] (36698 -> 37528) ... done
[ 70/119, 07:45/09:01] update: tcolorbox [3589k] (37258 -> 37530) ... done
[ 71/119, 07:56/08:56] update: tetex [393k] (37485 -> 37583) ... done
[ 72/119, 07:58/08:56] update: texinfo [90k] (37342 -> 37747) ... done
[ 73/119, 08:00/08:58] update: texlive-docindex [213k] (37512 -> 37740) ... done
[ 74/119, 08:01/08:58] update: texlive-msg-translations [110k] (37481 -> 37544) ... done
[ 75/119, 08:03/09:00] update: texlive-scripts [87k] (37482 -> 37696) ... done
[ 76/119, 08:06/09:02] update: tudscr [3388k] (36296 -> 37736) ... done
[ 77/119, 08:12/08:53] update: tufte-latex [464k] (24733 -> 37649) ... done
[ 78/119, 08:16/08:55] update: upmethodology [542k] (37038 -> 37694) ... done
[ 79/119, 08:19/08:56] update: urcls [429k] (36171 -> 37550) ... done
[ 80/119, 08:21/08:56] update: xetexko [259k] (36638 -> 37569) ... done
[ 81/119, 08:24/08:58] update: xindy [534k] (37078 -> 37716) ... done
[ 82/119, 08:27/08:59] update: zhnumber [338k] (35169 -> 37614) ... done
[ 83/119, 08:28/08:58] auto-install: academicons (37577) [84k] ... done
[ 84/119, 08:29/08:59] auto-install: arabi-add (37709) [168k] ... done
[ 85/119, 08:30/08:59] auto-install: biblatex-opcit-booktitle (37733) [93k] ... done
[ 86/119, 08:31/09:00] auto-install: bidihl (37746) [143k] ... done
[ 87/119, 08:32/09:00] auto-install: bookdb (37536) [212k] ... done
[ 88/119, 08:33/09:01] auto-install: br-lex (37725) [103k] ... done
[ 89/119, 08:34/09:01] auto-install: comicneue (37744) [822k] ... done
[ 90/119, 08:37/09:01] auto-install: diadia.universal-darwin (37645) [1k] ... done
[ 91/119, 08:37/09:01] auto-install: diadia.x86_64-darwin (37645) [1k] ... done
[ 92/119, 08:37/09:01] auto-install: elements (37723) [417k] ... done
[ 93/119, 08:39/09:01] auto-install: fithesis (37712) [2746k] ... done
[ 94/119, 08:46/08:56] auto-install: make4ht.universal-darwin (37750) [1k] ... done
[ 95/119, 08:46/08:56] auto-install: make4ht.x86_64-darwin (37750) [1k] ... done
[ 96/119, 08:46/08:56] auto-install: make4ht (37750) [75k] ... done
[ 97/119, 08:47/08:56] auto-install: mnras (37579) [259k] ... done
[ 98/119, 08:48/08:56] auto-install: ocgx2 (37620) [7k] ... done
[ 99/119, 08:48/08:56] auto-install: pdfbook2.universal-darwin (37537) [1k] ... done
[100/119, 08:49/08:57] auto-install: pdfbook2.x86_64-darwin (37537) [1k] ... done
[101/119, 08:49/08:57] auto-install: pdfbook2 (37537) [11k] ... done
[102/119, 08:50/08:58] auto-install: rmathbr (37663) [225k] ... done
[103/119, 08:52/08:59] auto-install: semproc (37568) [366k] ... done
[104/119, 08:54/09:00] auto-install: termmenu (37700) [472k] ... done
[105/119, 08:57/09:01] auto-install: tex4ebook (37751) [65k] ... done
[106/119, 08:57/09:00] auto-install: typicons (37623) [190k] ... done
[107/119, 08:58/09:01] auto-install: ucharcat (37529) [159k] ... done
[108/119, 08:59/09:01] auto-install: xpiano (37604) [553k] ... done
[109/119, 09:02/09:02] update: collection-bibtexextra [1k] (37359 -> 37536) ... done
[110/119, 09:03/09:03] update: collection-binextra [1k] (36355 -> 37751) ... done
[111/119, 09:04/09:04] update: collection-fontsextra [2k] (37396 -> 37744) ... done
[112/119, 09:05/09:05] update: collection-genericextra [1k] (37262 -> 37591) ... done
[113/119, 09:06/09:06] update: collection-langarabic [1k] (35139 -> 37746) ... done
[114/119, 09:07/09:07] update: collection-latexextra [5k] (37398 -> 37712) ... done
[115/119, 09:08/09:08] update: collection-luatex [1k] (34908 -> 37529) ... done
[116/119, 09:09/09:09] update: collection-mathextra [1k] (36538 -> 37535) ... done
[117/119, 09:10/09:10] update: collection-music [1k] (37024 -> 37604) ... done
[118/119, 09:11/09:11] update: collection-pictures [1k] (36373 -> 37604) ... done
[119/119, 09:12/09:12] update: collection-publishers [1k] (37300 -> 37710) ... done
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ...
done running mtxrun --generate.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
regenerating fmtutil.cnf in /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine ptex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine ptex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine aleph ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine aleph.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine eptex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine eptex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt jadetex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt jadetex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt mllatex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt mllatex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt mltex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt mltex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt lualatex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt lualatex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt latex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt latex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt csplain ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt csplain.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt pdfjadetex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt pdfjadetex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt pdfxmltex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt pdfxmltex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt xmltex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt xmltex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt dvilualatex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt dvilualatex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt pdfcslatex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt pdfcslatex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt pdfcsplain ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt pdfcsplain.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt pdflatex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt pdflatex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt cslatex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byfmt cslatex.

kp@mbp:Programs> echo $?
0

kp@mbp:Programs>
```

---

### Update 2

Running the *"Refresh Package List"* action item from the *TeX Live Utility.app* menu pops up this message:

> **Critical updates available.**
>
> 430 packages are available for update.  Of these, the TeX Live installer packages listed here must be updated first.  Update now?

It still shows the same 3 `texlive.infra*` packages as in the shots above. The command `sudo tlmgr update --all --self` however is happy now and does not want to update anything any more.

Also, `tlmgr` updated only 119 packages when it did, not 430. How can this discrepancy be explained?

Comment: Does `sudo tlmgr update --all --self` work?

Comment: Yes. It did complete with exit status 0, and seems to have upgraded 119 packages. -- Now running *TeX Live Utility.app* again indicates that there are *'Critical updates available. 430 packages available for updates. Of these, the TeX Live installer packages listed here must be updated first.  Update now?'* These listed installer packages are the same three as above. But update fails with the exact same message as shown in my OP saying l had the 2014 distribution, not the 2015 one.

Comment: DG': No, I've not gotten rid of the old distros (yet). Some of my shell scripts rely on them and their paths, and removing them will have to wait until I've gone through my scripts. Re-installing *TeX Live Utility.app* I've not yet explored, because befor your first hint about it I had thought it came as part of the TeXLive distribution and it could not be installed separately...

Comment: There are also known issues (https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/issues/18) and maybe it helps to manually change the repository.

Comment: @DG': Thx for the link to issue18.

Comment: Speaking as the TeX Live Utility developer, bypassing TLU by running commands in Terminal is a great way to ruin any chances of debugging a problem with it. The github issues page is the best place for reports like this.

Answer (score 2):

As requested by the maintainer of the TLU in a comment to my OP, I've submitted a new [bug report](https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/issues/20) about my issue.

It's solved now, and it wasn't a direct bug...

Lessons learned:

1. Check every line of the TLU log (access it via menu, *"Window -> Log Window"*). In my case it gave a hint about TLU including in its `$PATH` the `/usr/local/texlive/2014/` directory.
2. Don't be misled by the sub-optimal GUI for the TLU preferences setup. It looks like this...

   [image]

   ...and it is not re-sizeable, but it still lets you click on *Choose...* to set up a different `PATH`, the one to the `2015/` sub directory...

Comment: Since you installed via MacTeX and have the System Preferences pane, you should be using `/usr/texbin` (i.e., TLU's default setting, which would have avoided this entire problem) and **not** directly using the path for a specific TeX Live release. [Future releases of Mac OS X](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) may require a different path.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: how can I be using `/usr/texbin` ***when it is not even there?!?***  `/usr/local/texbin/2014/` and `/usr/local/texbin/2015/` are where the default installation routines of MacTex 2014/2015 installed their stuff, and where I then discovered it. I didn't tweak anything while installing it. -- All this is pretty confusing, and badly documented, if you ask me...

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you've done, it's hard to say what happened. If you installed via MacTeX, then you should have `/usr/texbin`, which is a symbolic link to TeX and associated binaries, and the System Preferences pane you showed above allows switching between TL 2013/2014/2015/etc.

Comment: Previous comment was accidentally saved while incomplete. I recommend you read the [detailed documentation (PDF)](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/BasicTeX.pdf) and follow up if you have further questions.